# Make function and "commands commence before first target"?

Tags: bash, function, makefile, gnu-make

Here is the command I run

```
make -d -f dump.makefile
```

A the error I got:

```
Reading makefile `dump.makefile'...
dump.makefile:31: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

#### Source

```
ifneq (,)
This makefile requires GNU Make.
endif

# force use of Bash
SHELL := /bin/bash


# function
today=$(shell date '+%Y-%m:%b-%d')
update-latest=$(shell ln -nf {$(call today),latest}.cfdict-"$(1)".localhot.sql)

# variables
credentials="$$HOME/.my.cfdict.cnf"

default: data-only structure-only csv-only all

data-only: what=data
    argList=( --defaults-file="${credentials}" --no-create-db --no-create-info ) \
    mysqldump "$${argList[@]}" cfdict > $(call today).cfdict-"${what}".localhot.sql
    $(call update-latest,${what})
```

The line that trigger the error is `$(call update-latest,${what})` with call the `update-latest` function.

Full [gist available on github](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/9963270#file-dump-mk-L31).

#### Question

I check for tabs/space, it seems correct.
Did I misuse the `call` or badly declare `update-latest` ?

Comment: Try `update-latest=$(shell echo ln ...` to see what the shell gets. I wonder if the $(call today) is substituted before the ln command is handed off to the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that causes the error you report is that you do not separate the target-specific variable definitions from the definitions of the rules. You currently have rules of this form:

```
data-only: what=data
        ... commands ...
```

You might be expecting that the `data-only: what=data` line defines the target-specific variable and the rule, but it does not.

What you need is to have o**ne line for the variable declaration and then repeat the name of the target for the rule**. Like this:

```
data-only: what=data
data-only:
        ... commands ...
```

So `data-only`, to take just one example, would become:

```
data-only: what=data
data-only:
    argList=( --defaults-file="${credentials}" --no-create-db --no-create-info ) \
    mysqldump "$${argList[@]}" cfdict > $(call today).cfdict-"${what}".localhot.sql
    $(call update-latest,${what})
```

I see that you declare `argList` as a shell variable so it does not need to be changed.

You'll have to update similarly all targets that have target-specific variables in your Makefile.

Comment: I went to a more `make`-like approach thanks to @joshc user on ##workingset. See [updated gist](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/9963270/23709405f0d34e2d19e28c78c420913219b6ff5e)

Comment: Yeah, that's a radical transformation. What I'm seeing there is the result of a complete code review.